# How to stop rails from keep checking old application.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to solve this: `couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.effect-blind'`
issue. I follow some suggestions and try to change `application.js` file.
Before I make changes, I saved `application.js` to `application.js.original`.

But I keep getting the same error because Rails is keep checking
the original application.js which is `application.js.original`.

I tred to use `application.js.original`, so I made a copy as `application.js.original.original` :):):)

But again, Rails is checking `application.js.original.original`.

How can I stop that. So that Rails will only check `application.js`?

I then made changes to `application.js.original.original` since
Rails is keep check that file, but then I got `application.js.original
has already been required`. I think Rails is kinda too smart:)

Comment: Are you referencing the jq-ui.effect-blind anywhere in the app?

Comment: not that I know of:)

Comment: Using jquery Ui gem?